# Django forms CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-2.2

Im trying to change a form from RadioSelect to MultipleChoice

with this form, I can see and the form in my tempalte as RadioButtons and can fill and save.

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                   widget=RadioSelect)
```

But, when I change to

```
 widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple
```

Then I can see and select all Choices, but after saving the page is reloading without saving.

```
class TestTake(FormView):
    form_class = TestForm
    template_name = 'question.html'
    result_template_name = 'result.html'
    single_complete_template_name = 'single_complete.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
        if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user,
                                                        self.quiz)
        else:
            self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()

        if self.sitting is False:
            return render(request, self.single_complete_template_name)

        return super(TestTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

How can I insert a Multiple Select checkbox here?

Comment: Have you tried using a MultipleChoiceField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

Comment: I tried         `choice_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=question.objects.all())
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                   widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)` But then I get a new error: Manager isn't accessible via Question instances